# How do you combine two arguments using JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following script but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to combine two arguments. Basically I would like to launch an action when my when a user is using an IPad and has a browser width less than 1025. When I run each argument individually they work, so I believe that the syntax is wrong:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

      $(window).resize(function(){
        var is_iPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
        var browidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth; 

          if ((is_iPad) && (browidth < 1025)) { 

                      alert('Ipad');
          }
    });
```

Comment: Your syntax is fine. What issues are you having with this piece of code? Does it just not trigger your alert?

Comment: @Ben Beck Yeah It's not triggering the alert

Comment: Trace out is_Pad && browWidth. If for instance "browWidth" isn't an actual number (maybe parseInt it), this can go wonky (and of course if either value is falsy, it'll fail). Also, to find out if the values are actually resolving to true or false, you can do console.log ( !!browidth ), and console.log ( !!is_iPad ) (bang-bang boolean is a quick way to test just about anything for truthy/falsy).

Comment: Be sure to resize then it should run

Comment: Haha yes as Novice says (I had assumed it but I've done that sort of thing more than once so...)

Comment: @ Novice Thanks Novice! I caught that. Ugh, I forgot that I had it on